# Overlaying text on animated GIF with gm quite slow

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, animated-gif, gm

I'm using this bit of code to call [`gm`](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) in Node.js to overlay text on animated GIFs:

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm(infile)
    .stroke("#000000")
    .fill('#ffffff')
    .font("./impact.ttf", 42)
    .dither(false)
    .drawText(0, 0, text, 'South')
    .write(outfile, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Image processing done.');
        }
        else console.log(err);
});
```

It works fine, however a bit on the slow side. I think (or at least i hope) i can do better.

Now, that thing really translates to (i spied on `gm`):

```
$ convert /tmp/input.gif -stroke "#000000" -fill "#ffffff" \
          -pointsize 42 -font ./impact.ttf \
          -draw "gravity south text 0,0 SOME TEXT" \
          -dither None output.gif
```

This takes about 30 seconds to process.

I've tried a few things:

- Adding `-colors 128` shaves off around 7 seconds (but if the original .gif is 256 colors, some quality is lost).
- `-coalesce` adds 20 more seconds to the 30, no go.

The text is overlay on every frame, here's the final product (NOT the .gif i'm testing with - just a sample):

[image: moneyburn]

### QUESTION #1

Is there anything i can do to make this faster, other than throw more compute at it? I'm open to lowering image quality.. but you know.. sensibly.

### QUESTION #2

How would i go about getting some progress indicator in my frontend?
Can i listen for an event that has an approximate idea of how much data/time remains? An example would be fantastic.

Since all i'm doing is change a few pixels at the bottom on the input GIF, the live file size of input GIF vs resulting GIF is a pretty good indicator of how much time is left, but wondering if there's a better approach.

#### EDIT:

This is the GIF i'm testing with:
https://m.popkey.co/bca7ab/ygQJw.gif

```
$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 i686 2016-06-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms
           lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: Mmm, that's odd - it takes 0.3s on my iMac. Have you got OpenCL enabled by any chance - try `identify -version`

Comment: I'm running in AWS on a tiny instance. I don't have OpenCL ..or a GPU.

Comment: Oh and more importantly I'm testing with a 10MB gif. Not the one above.

Comment: Try running `identify -list resource` and seeing how much memory is available to ImageMagick. If on the low side, you can increase the RAM available to ImageMagick with `convert -limit memory 512MiB ... usual stuff ...` You can also debug paging out to disk with `convert -debug cache .... usual stuff ...` You could also use `convert -debug all ...` to get an idea of progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are running the Q16 version with 16-bit quantisation and that is probably overkill if you are happy with 128 colour GIFs anyway.

I got a 50% time reduction (albeit from 6s to 3s) on my desktop iMac by changing from the 16-bit to the 8-bit version. To get the 8-bit version, you need to rebuild using:

```
./configure --with-quantum-depth=8 ... your usual options...
```

Not only does that speed things up, but it also relieves *"memory pressure"* so it may help your application in other ways too by minimising paging.

You could also try adding in `--enable-zero-configuration` to prevent **ImageMagick** reading lots of XML config files at startup.

Some things run faster without OpenMP, so you could also consider disabling that when you run `./configure`.

See also my comment about resources:

```
identify -list resource
```

and maybe increasing the memory available to **ImageMagick** using:

```
convert -limit memory 512MiB ....
```

As regards following progress, you could use `-monitor` like this:

```
convert -monitor anim.gif -stroke "#000000" -fill "#ffffff" -pointsize 42 -draw "gravity south text 0,0 'SOME TEXT'" -dither None output.gif
```

**Sample Output**

```
load image[anim.gif]: 1 of 2, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 2 of 3, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 3 of 4, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 4 of 5, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 5 of 6, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 6 of 7, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 7 of 8, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 8 of 9, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 9 of 10, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 10 of 11, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 11 of 12, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 12 of 13, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 13 of 14, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 14 of 15, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 15 of 16, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 16 of 17, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 17 of 18, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 18 of 19, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 19 of 20, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 20 of 21, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 21 of 22, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 22 of 23, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 23 of 24, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 24 of 25, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 25 of 26, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 26 of 27, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 27 of 28, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 28 of 29, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 29 of 30, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 30 of 31, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 31 of 32, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 32 of 33, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 33 of 34, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 34 of 35, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 35 of 36, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 36 of 37, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 37 of 38, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 38 of 39, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 39 of 40, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 40 of 41, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 41 of 42, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 42 of 43, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 43 of 44, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 44 of 45, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 45 of 46, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 46 of 47, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 47 of 48, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 48 of 49, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 49 of 50, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 50 of 51, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 51 of 52, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 52 of 53, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 53 of 54, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 54 of 55, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 55 of 56, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 56 of 57, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 57 of 58, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 58 of 59, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 59 of 60, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 60 of 61, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 61 of 62, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 62 of 63, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 63 of 64, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 64 of 65, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 65 of 66, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 66 of 67, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 67 of 68, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 68 of 69, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 69 of 70, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 70 of 71, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 71 of 72, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 72 of 73, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 73 of 74, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 74 of 75, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 75 of 76, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 76 of 77, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 77 of 78, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 78 of 79, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 79 of 80, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 80 of 81, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 81 of 82, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 82 of 83, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 83 of 84, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 84 of 85, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 85 of 86, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 86 of 87, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 87 of 88, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 88 of 89, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 89 of 90, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 90 of 91, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 91 of 92, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 92 of 93, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 93 of 94, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 94 of 95, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 95 of 96, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 96 of 97, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 97 of 98, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 98 of 99, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 99 of 100, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 100 of 101, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 101 of 102, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 102 of 103, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 103 of 104, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 104 of 105, 100% complete
load image[anim.gif]: 105 of 106, 100% complete
mogrify image[anim.gif]: 106 of 107, 100% complete
classify image colors[output.gif]: 313 of 314, 100% complete
assign image colors[output.gif]: 313 of 314, 100% complete
classify image colors[output.gif]: 313 of 314, 100% complete
...
...
```

Comment: That's probably the worst progress indicator of all time, but it's not your fault. Here's the bounty! Thanks for the effort and for well documenting your answer!